# get total when adding a new row and decrease when removing row

Tags: jquery

I'm doing some operations in my table, so if a user adds a new row its possible to set up a quantity, unit price and the total gets calculated automatically. This happens on each row. I'm trying to get the total below the table to be accumulated when each row is added. Otherwise should decrease when a row is removed.

Up to now I'm getting only the total value of the row I'm setting.

```
$('.tablePuc, .tablePus, .tableQuantity').live('keyup', function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); // all based on parent row
    var unitPc = $row.find('.tablePuc').val();
    var unitPs = $row.find('.tablePus').val();
    var qty = $row.find('.tableQuantity').val();
    var imp = 0.21;
    var totalSimp = unitPs * qty;
    var totalCimp = unitPc * qty + ((unitPc * qty) * imp);
    if (totalCimp) {
        $row.find('.tableTotal').val(totalCimp);
    } else if (totalSimp) {
        $row.find('.tableTotal').val(totalSimp);
    }
    $('#labelResult').html(totalSimp);
    $('#labelResult2').html(totalCimp);
});
```

Example can be seen on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q6mb/)

Comment: You may take a look at [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/). This scenario may be well addressed by this framework.

Answer (score 0):

.live should be removed and use .on instead!

Aside from that:

```
var rowCount = $('#table_id >tbody >tr').length;  //rowCount = number of rows of the table tbody!
```

You can use it after each add/delete to recalculate the total number of rows, or just store it in a variable and increase/decrease it as fit. I would probable recalculate it each time, since the table isn't big.

You can use it this way too:

```
sum=0;
$('#table_id >tbody >tr').children().eq(n).each(function(){ //n is the row column where u want to get the data
     sum+=$(this).val();
});
```

If you want to do all the row children in one go:

```
sum=[];
$('#table_id >tbody >tr').each(function(){
     x=0; 
     $(this).children().each(function(){ 
         sum[x]+=$(this).val();
         x++;
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over all your lines in your table... Something like that should work :

```
$('table').on('keyup', '.tablePuc, .tablePus, .tableQuantity', updateTotal);


function updateTotal() {
    var totalSimpGlobal = 0;
    var totalCimpGlobal = 0;

    $("#tableSo").find("tr:gt(0)").each(function() {
        var $row = $(this); // all based on parent row
        var unitPc = $row.find('.tablePuc').val();
        var unitPs = $row.find('.tablePus').val();
        var qty = $row.find('.tableQuantity').val();
        var imp = 0.21;
        var totalSimp = unitPs * qty;
        totalSimpGlobal += totalSimp;
        var totalCimp = unitPc * qty + ((unitPc * qty) * imp);
        totalCimpGlobal += totalCimp;
        if (totalCimp) {
        $row.find('.tableTotal').val(totalCimp);
        } else if (totalSimp) {
            $row.find('.tableTotal').val(totalSimp);
        }

    });

    $('#labelResult').html(totalSimpGlobal);
    $('#labelResult2').html(totalCimpGlobal);
}
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3zV2G/3.

---

**EDIT**

I have updated the first line in order to deal with the new lines.

Comment: I have tried the jsfiddle.. but is not working when i add a new row..=/

Comment: Sorry, I have forget this aspect : with `on`, you should be based on an existing element : [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zV2G/3/).